# How to send via POST accented characters in ASP.NET ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest

I would like to know how to send via POST method, UTF-8 encoded characters in ASP.NET.

With my code, it's working but not with accented characters (like ô, ê, é è). I receive an Error 500 (internal server error)

In php, I use the functions utf8_encode() and after urlencode() and it's working !

Thank you for you help

Here my code :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.website.com");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "login=xxx&password=xxx&postblog=My message. Problem with accented characters like ô ê é è ";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
...
response.Close();
```

Comment: maybe you should post more details about the server side.  You've verified that removing the accent characters stops the 500 error?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is it, but your ContentType isn't quite correct.  Try this

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
```

Comment: thank you. I have tried but no it's not working. I have all the time an error 500 in response.